Are net work and total work done on a body the same numerical value?
I came across this question in JEE Main (2022) which states:
"a body of mass 0.5 kg is moving on a straight line with a velocity v= (3x^2 + 4)m/s. The net work done by the force during it's displacement from x=0 to x=2 is?"
when I applied the line integral of $f.dx$ on this question I got 6 joules, but from work energy theorem the answer is 60J. I observed that work energy theorem gives net work done while the integral gives total work done. Are they actually different quantities or is my assessment wrong?

What force do you use in the integral? There is no force given in your text of the problem.

The force is not given, but the average force times the displacement will equal the change in kinetic energy.

@BobD please reopen the question. There is not enough reason to close this. Further, I have the answer to this.

In general it is true that the net work and the total work need not be the same thing. However the discrepancies occur in situations where a force is applied on a part of the system that is not moving at the velocity of the center of mass. That doesn’t seem to be the case here, so I suspect this specific case is simply a mistake in the math.
